# Jackson databind JSON boolean conversion

Tags: java, json, jackson, pojo

I'm using Jackson objectMapper to convert a JSON to an object and do some transformations and converting it back to JSON.

The JSON is like `{ "id":"abc1243", "val":1, "isDel":true}`

In the above val is int and isDel is boolean.

My object is defined as below

```
public class MyObj{
  private String id;
  private String val;
  private String isDel;
   //getters and setters

}
```

When I convert the JSON to the MyObj, the String id and Int val are bound into the String but the boolean is not binded and hence I get null.

Im using the below approach

```
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    try {
        MyObj myObj = mapper.readValue(new File("/Users/sample.json"), MyObj.class);
}
```

May I know why the boolean is not binded to the String member.

Comment: Quick question, since you want a boolean field why don't you just set it as this in the pojo itself?

Comment: Have you tried ` private boolean isDel;` instead of ` private String isDel;`?

Comment: Or change `{ "id":"abc1243", "val":1, "isDel":true}` to `{ "id":"abc1243", "val":1, "isDel":"true"}` basically treat String as String

Comment: @bhantol indeed this could work true but again the question remains, why not just a boolean field.

Comment: @Aris I need to use this pojo to generate a strict JSON as the api that I would be posting this requires it. like "false" and not false

Comment: you can use custom serializer and deserializer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a setter that accepts boolean and does the necessary conversion

```
@JsonProperty("isDel")
public void setIsDel(boolean isDel) {
  this.isDel = String.valueOf(isDel);
}
```

note: this does not interfere with a setter that accepts String (the annotation tells Jackson to use this particular method)

Answer (score 0):

It is natural to map `boolean` in JSON to boolean in Java.

[Checkout line 141 deserializeIfNatural()](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/jsontype/TypeDeserializer.java#L141) where the token type is tested with the class using `base.isAssignableFrom(Boolean.class)` and in this case it is not assignable because it is String hence not mapped.