# How to convert a @requestBody to a customized object?

Tags: java, spring-boot, controller

I am using springboot controller with @RequestBody.  I have following json request body

```
{
  "abc":"xyz",
  "valid":"yes"
}
```

I have a corresponding POJO

```
class MyObject{
  private String abc;
  private Boolean valid;
}
```

I have controller like

```
@PostMapping(value = "somePath", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<MyResponse>  myMethod(@RequestBody MyObject request)  {
```

Obviously it won't work because `valid` is a string in request whereas it is boolean in MyObject. I want it to have a logic so if `valid=yes` is in request it will be converted to boolean `true` in MyObject. Any mechanism does spring has to achieve that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jackson databind JSON boolean conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48412266/jackson-databind-json-boolean-conversion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible if you annotate your `MyObject` with jackson annotations: in this case you can create an all args constructor with the [`JsonCreator`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html) annotation and define there your expected behaviour:

```
public class MyObject {

    private String abc;
    private Boolean valid;

    @JsonCreator
    public MyObject(String abc, String valid) {
        this.abc = abc;
        if (valid.equals("yes")) {
            //be aware valid will remain null 
            //if valid is different from yes
            this.valid = true; 
        }
    }

}
```